Contents of writable volume on Ubuntu Live USB disappear on reboot
I set up a live USB with Ubuntu 22.04 (I believe I used Startup Disk Creator) a while ago.
The drive has a partition named writable. When I mount that in a normal Ubuntu install, I see it contains folders named install-logs-2023-03-07.0 and similar. Each has subfolders named crash and log.
When I boot the live image, I see the partition gets mounted twice: once as /var/crash and once as /var/log. I can place files in there, but although mount shows identical mount paths, files I placed in one folder do not appear in the other.
When I reboot into a new live session, content I previously saved in /var/crash is no longer visible. However, Disks shows the free space on the partition has decreased.
When I mount the partition in a normal Ubuntu install, I see a new install-logs-YYYY-MM-DD.N folder has been created for each live session. The crash folder of the first session has the files I created in that session. However, I have not found a way to access them from a live session.
Although mount shows /dev/sda4 for both mount points (/etc/mtab has /dev/disk/by-label/writable for both), something is causing a fresh sub-subdir for that particular live session to get mounted instead of the partition root dir, though I haven‘t found out how that is implemented.
How can I access data stored by a previous live session, or otherwise persist data across live sessions?

Change the label of the writable partition to something else. This will prevent the live session from mounting it with whatever magic it does, allowing you to mount the root of the partition manually.
In a full install, with the drive plugged in but not mounted (unmount if necessary), do something like the following:
sudo tune2fs -L usbdata /dev/sdx9

Instead of /dev/sdx9, use the actual device path to your partition. You may use the label of your choice instead of usbdata.
Boot into a live session. The partition will no longer get mounted automatically, you will have to do that yourself (e.g. using Disks – this will also show you the mount path).
That gave me access to all the log and crash data from previous sessions (read-only unless you use sudo). You can also create new folders (using sudo, then chown to the live session user) and place files in them which will be preserved across sessions and can also be opened from a regular Ubuntu install.
